# S3 to MySQL AWS Data Pipeline Insert table error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

It's my first time asking a question on here, please so bear with me

I am trying to create a data pipeline to upload a CSV file in an S3-Bucket to a MySQL database table(Production1) using the template provided by aws, but fails when executing RdsMySqlTableCreateActivity.

The sql statement that I'm using(all column names match the CSV file) in the myRDSTableInsertSql parameter:

```
INSERT INTO `Production1` (`API`, `Normalized Month`, `DATE`, `Monthly Liquid`, `Cum Oil`, `BOPD`, `Monthly Gas Mcf/Month`, `Cum Gas`, `MCFPD`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

The RdsMySqlTableCreateActivity error:

```
errorId
ActivityFailed:SQLException
errorMessage
No value specified for parameter 1
errorStackTrace
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: 
private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.redshift.QueryStatementException: Exception No value specified for 
parameter 1 while executing INSERT INTO `Production1` (`API`, `Normalized Month`, `DATE`, `Monthly Liquid`, `Cum Oil`, `BOPD`, `Monthly Gas Mcf/Month`, `Cum Gas`, `MCFPD`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);...
```

I ran the insert command on MySQL workbench, replacing the `(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` with `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`, and it worked. The CSV file that I'm using only has 2 rows the column names and values 1-9 for each column respectively. Really not sure what it means by `No value specified for parameter 1`, any help/guidance would really be appreciated!!!

Comment: Are there any empty values in the API field in your CSV? Is your first row Data or Headers?

Comment: The first row is a header, there are no empty values, its just 2 rows

Comment: When you ran this in MySQL workbench, you replaced the question marks with values. Does it work the same if you create an empty db and run the insert command against the new db? Hence, I am not sure if your issue is related to the data, the query or Pipeline.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, but I went on MySQL workbench and the command works as long as I run a CREATE TABLE command first.

Comment: I am going to try to import the CSV file in workbench, just to make sure its not an db or file issue

Comment: Ok, so I ran the Insert table command,  then imported the CSV file into the table in workbench and it worked 
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file location' INTO TABLE Production
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that runs into the same issue using the "Load S3 data into RDS MySQL table" template

My values for each parameter were the following

myRDSTableInsertSql:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(`col_name1`, `col_name2`, `col_name3`, `col_name4`, `col_name5`, `col_name6`, `col_name7`, `col_name8`, `col_name9`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

myRDSTableName: `tableName`

myRDSCreateTableSql:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName(`col_name1` type, `col_name2` type, `col_name3` type, `col_name4` type, `col_name5` type, `col_name6` type, `col_name7` type, `col_name8` type, `col_name9` type);
```

The main issue was with the actual CSV file format, you have to make sure there is no header, and that the types are exactly the same. Also make sure that you're separators are "," and each value is not quoted within your CSV file.

This template is a good starting point but form more detailed/complex CSV files making your own datapipeline is a must!

Comment: Can you please help me to understand what do you mean by making my own datapipeline? I am struggling with this for almost two days now. :(

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Upload CSV to MySQL or the specifically the data pipeline ?

Comment: I can upload CSV to MySQL in my local machine. But when I am trying to do the same in PipeLine I get the error.

Comment: The same issue I'm facing now. Error Message: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.